# Proving a left ideal in a direct sum is also a right ideal.

Tags: ring-theory

Assume that $R$ is a ring with $1$ such that every $R$ module is injective. I've proved that $R$ is the finite direct sum of left ideals. I want to write $R$ as a ring direct product of $2$-sided ideals which have no sub-$2$-sided-ideals (so the factors are all simple/irreducible modules). The first step is to choose a minimal $2$-sided ideal $R_1$. Since $R$ is injective, we can decompose it as the direct sum of left ideals $R_1\oplus R'$. Now, I need to show that $R'$ is also a right ideal, which is where I'm stuck.

So say $r\in R'$, $s\in R$. In the direct sum, we would decompose as follows $r'=0+r'$. If we right multiply both sides by $s$, then we get $r's=0+r's$. Now, since $r's\in R$, then we can decompose it as $a+b$, where $a\in R_1$, $b\in R'$. Then we have $r's=a+b$, and now I'm not sure how to proceed. I need to prove that $r's=b$, or equivalently, that $a=0$, but I don't see any obvious reason why this must be true.

Comment: This is the structure theorem for semisimple rings. See, for instance, http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter9.pdf

Comment: I know; the purpose of the exercise is to prove this theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I understand that proof, but I'm still curious as to how one would do it in the way I had described.

Comment: I don't think you can do it that way.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd, since I got this exercise from Dummit and Foote:
http://s29.postimg.org/haltwbaev/dfpage.jpg

Comment: Well, try harder. ;-)

Comment: Given $R_1$, there are in general many choices of left ideals $R'$ such that $R=R_1\oplus R'$, but only some of them will also be right ideals.

Comment: Is there a way to pick the right one? Also, can you give me an example?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question; actually $R'$ is unique. Hint for the original question: Write $1=e+f$ for $e\in R_1$ and $f\in R'$ and see what you can prove about $e$ and $f$. Aim to show that $R'=fR$ and is therefore a right ideal.

Comment: Oh, so since $1^2=e^2+f^2+2ef$, and $ef\in R_1\cap R'$, it's equal to $0$, so $1=e^2+f^2$. Also, by uniqueness of $1$'s representation, both $e$ and $f$ are idempotents. Both are also central, so since $R'=Rf$, it is also the case that $R'=fR$.

Comment: @Nishant Can you explain how you know $e$ and $f$ are central?

Comment: Uh, I think it's because $e$ and $f$ are the unique elements of the direct summands that add to $1$, so they are in fact the multiplicative identities within the direct summands.